# Converting TSQL to JSON

Tags: sql, json, t-sql

Update 3-12-13: I have fixed this problem by using a normal SQL query and pasting the right brackets and quotes between the data. When I copy and paste this result to my JSON file the list is updated.

Thank you for your help all.

I have a problem with parsing data I get from my database to a JSON output. I've never used TSQL but it seems like the best way to do it. The desired JSON output is this:

```
{
     "persons": {
     "person": [
     {
    "name": "Kevin Wtenweerde",
    "phone": "231",
    "mobile": "0612345678"
     }
    ]
  }
}
```

My database table is called list and has the fields name, phone and mobile.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: There's a Phil Factor post on SimpleTalk which provides to- and from- JSON functions for TSQL - https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: I saw this post before, I tried to use this but I couldn't get it to work. Do you have any idea how I can implement this for this specific result?

Comment: That's an interesting mix of English properties and ?Dutch? object and collection names.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed, wanted to make the list english but forgot a bit, rest is dutch haha. Edited it!

Comment: If you expand on 'couldn't get it to work' we might be able to help.

Comment: I'll try it step by step again and post back later what went wrong. ty!

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it *as* an answer. Don't edit it into your question.

Answer (score 3):

T-SQL is not the appropriate language to to do this job. Use T-SQL (as well as any other SQL flavor) to manipulate sets and to retrieve results from the database. A primer SQL is beyond the point here. One you have the desired result in your process, use your favorite JSON library to create the JSON and then serve it to whatever your consumer is.

Yes, there will be mavericks that will show some TSQL code that creates JSON. Heck, I've seen TSQL that creates raw PDFs. Just because is possible, doesn't mean you should. There are factors to consider like maintenability, readability, where are the back-end CPU cycles best spent, etc etc.

Comment: I need this JSON file for a internal phone list. I am using SQL Management Studio 2008. Can I use a JSON library within this?

Comment: I understand, problem is that I got this assignment for a school project. So I have to use T-SQL to retrieve the JSON list:)

Comment: You can't be serious. What kind of teacher would ask for such an anti-pattern??

Comment: Yeah we need to do lots of weird assignments in my opionon. Thanks for trying to help me do the right thing though!